# Canonical url differs from custom post type archive URLs

Tags: custom-post-types, rewrite-rules, custom-post-type-archives

I cannot figure out how to control canonical URL for custom post type archive pages.

Here's my excerpt of CPT setting for `soccer_club` for example. This CPT supports default category taxonomy.

```
$args = array(
...
    "public" => true,
    "show_ui" => true,
    "has_archive" => true,
    "capability_type" => "post",
    "map_meta_cap" => true,
    "hierarchical" => false,
    "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "soccer/%category%",
                 "with_front" => true ),
    "query_var" => true,
    "taxonomies" => array( "category" ) // support default category taxonomy
);
register_post_type( "soccer_club", $args );
```

I used `%category%` for the slug to control the permalink of single post under category like `uncategorized`. I remove it via the filter called `post_type_link`.

Then I set my custom rewrite rules to the filter `generate_rewrite_rules`.

I also have two category terms `news` and `blogs` and let them being displayed on same archive page `http://mysportssite.com/soccer/update/`.

```
function custom_rewrite_rules($wp_rewrite) {
    $my_custom_url = array(
        '(soccer|baseball|tennis)/?$' =>
        'index.php?post_type=$matches[1]',
    ...
        '(soccer|baseball|tennis)/update/?$' =>
        'index.php?post_type=$matches[1]&category_name=news,blogs',
    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $my_custom_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;

}
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'custom_rewrite_rules' );
```

URL rewrite function works OK. So far so good.

I activated [YoastSEO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) plugin to generate canonical url.
When I looked at source code it generated wrong canonical url. Looks like this:

```
http://mysportssite.com/soccer/%category%
```

Or on /update/ archive page

```
http://mysportssite.com/category/news
```

These should be like

```
http://mysportssite.com/soccer/
http://mysportssite.com/soccer/update/
```

It doesn't seem that the filter `generate_rewrite_rules` takes effect on canonical urls.

I suppose this doesn't have to do with YoastSEO. There would be same problem if I use other plugins to generate canonical urls.
Are there any functions or filters to alter or generate correct canonical urls?

Comment: Just to quick answer my question, I can retrieve requested URI from `$wp` object. I dont know if this is the correct way, but `$wp->request` is what I was looking for. Then do this maybe, `add_query_arg( $wp->query_string, '', home_url( $wp->request ) );`

Comment: And without Yoast SEO? WordPress generates canonical URLs for single posts of any type, Does WordPress do it correctly without YoastSEO? Please, note that [questions about third party plugins are off-topic here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic); you should contact to YoastSEO support instead.

Comment: Yes, Wordpress generates correct canonical URL for a single post. So I use conditional function (like `is_singular()`) to mute canonical URL for a single post. Since I use `$wp->request` for post type archive pages I probably don't need Yoast SEO.

Comment: just fyi- rewrite rules only handle incoming requests, there is no "awareness" of custom rewrite rules on the output side. we've been waiting for [a filter on `re_canonical`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18660) for a while now...